# All the properties of $\operatorname{cis}$ operator using De Moivre's formula

Tags: complex-numbers, soft-question, education

I know that

$$\boxed{(\operatorname{cis}(\varphi))^n=(\cos \varphi +i \sin \varphi)^n\equiv \cos(n\varphi)+i\sin(n\varphi)} \tag 1$$

> I would like to know if there are several **properties** of the $\operatorname{cis}$ operator using De Moivre's formula further this:
> $$\operatorname{cis}(\phi)^n=\operatorname{cis}(n\phi)$$

Comment: See [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4208184/815585) answer of mine

Comment: It is essentially the same, just replace the roots with powers $\gt1$

Comment: @FShrike Thank you very much and I give you my thanks.

Comment: Like $\operatorname{cis}(x+y)=\operatorname{cis}(x)\operatorname{cis}(y)$?

Comment: I have corrected "proprieties" $\to$ properties.

Comment: @JeanMarie Thank you very very much $\ddot \smile$. Sometimes my Italian language is go out here.

Comment: @J.G. Hi :-) but is it like the $\log$ or $\exp$ properties? Thank you very much also for you.

Comment: @Sebastiano The property I mentioned is like $\exp$ (indeed, $\operatorname{cis}(x)=\exp{ix}$, but maybe that's a spoiler for what comes next).

Comment: @J.G. It is true :-(....I not remembered. :-(((( However I am glad to receive a gradite answer. :-)